# hide div in one area after show in jquery code igniter

Tags: php, javascript, json, codeigniter, jquery

i have a div named "hide" in one area of a view page ... i want to hide it against the response of ajax ... here is my code .. first i am hiding a div at the start so i write  $('#hide').hide(); just after the ready function ...then i am showing the div in else part.. so now i want is i want to again hide it  if response is 'userNo'...all is working except div is not hiding again..i dont know why what is the problem

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#hide').hide();
    $('#bill_no').blur(function(){

        if( $('#bill_no').val().length >= 3 )
            {
              var bill_no = $('#bill_no').val();
              getResult(bill_no); 
            }
        return false;
    })
    function getResult(billno){
        var baseurl = $('.hiddenUrl').val();
       $('.check').addClass('preloader');
        $.ajax({
            url : baseurl + 'returnFromCustomer_Controller/checkBillNo/' + billno,
            cache : false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(response){
                 $('.check').removeClass('preloader');

                if (response == "userNo") 
                    $('#hide').hide();  // this is not working 
                else
                $('.check').removeClass('userNo').addClass('userOk');
                // $(".text").html(response.result);
                 $('#hide').show();
                 $(".text1").html(response.result1);
                 $(".text2").html(response.result2);
                 $(".text3").html(response.result3);

            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you sure the response is indeed 'userNo'?

Answer (score 1):

Oh well, you hide the div, then you show it again in your 2nd line of code after the 'else' statement! So it appears to you that your code is not working. Your code flows like this:
if response is 'userNo', hide the div, otherwise remove/add some class on $('.check'). In either case, show the div and replace the html of the three text divs. Since your show div statement is outside of the if/else case.

You should always use {} after an if/else statement, if not then only the first statement immediately after the if/else gets executed. So you should do

```
if (response == 'userNo') {
  $('#hide').hide();
} else {
  $('.check').removeClass('userNo').addClass('userOk');
  $('#hide').show();
  $(".text1").html(response.result1);
  $(".text2").html(response.result2);
  $(".text3").html(response.result3);
}
```